# How to run %cd using a variable on ipython (google colab)?

Tags: ipython, cd

I want to access folders shared to me on drive, I have created a shortcut on my drive and I wanna access it from there.
The problem I'm facing is I want to change directory using variable. But when I use this code:

```
for boxNo in range(109):
  boxStr = "/gdrive/My Drive/Box Set {}".format(boxNo)
  %cd -q setStr  # The problem is here
  url = !pwd
  print("I have to use this url: " + url[0])
```

I get this error:

*`[Errno 0] No such file or directory: 'setStr'`*

> **SIDE-NOTE:**
>  `echo` or `!echo` both don't work either as I write `echo url[0]` it displays `url[0]` on the output. But inside parenthesis, as in print, `print(url[0])`, it
> works. My guess is if I could change directory keeping the variable inside parenthesis it
> would work but I seem to find no way of doing so.

Comment: There might not be a convenient way of combining the two. Is there no way around having to navigate like that?

Comment: also the variable should probably be `boxStr` instead of `setStr`

Comment: Try `%cd -q $boxStr`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$` before the variable name

```
  %cd -q $setStr
```